# Reconcile PuTTY and OpenSSH with git remote URL

Tags: windows, git, virtual-machine, putty, openssh

On a local development machine, I use Windows and PuTTY, with a linux server VM that I use to replicate the development environment for things like running tests and so forth. The VM (VirtualBox) uses a vboxfs share that contains my local projects.

I have set up msysgit on my machine to use PuTTY, my preferred SSH client, and that all works fine. Unfortunately, when I set a git remote URL, it has to use PuTTY's format to specify a session (`ssh://<session name>/<repo>`) in order for msysgit to work, which means none of the git urls work in the VM environment. This isn't a huge deal, but I was curious: Is there a way to reconcile the two configurations so I can use git commands in either environment without manually setting a remote url each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work-around is to install PuTTY on your Linux machine. There are several precompiled versions out there or you can just download the official source and compile them.

Comment: Hey, not even something I'd considered. SO SIMPLE.